# How to use Decodable with Generics & Core data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, core-data, decodable

Below is my JSON. I need to decode the entries in it using "Decodable" CoreData model class. The Entries(and corresponding model classes in Core data) are different as you can see against key "c". So this variable "c" needs to be of type generic  i guess. So it can accept all 6(fixed!) types of models viz. "consultation_time", "child", "appointment", "child_doctor", "clinic", "clinic_user". Not sure how to implement this .
Model classes generated by core data.(Have used https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/96860#295158 this link to implement Decodable with Coredata.)

Updates+CoreDataClass.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


public class Updates: NSManagedObject {

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(name ?? "" , forKey: .name)
    try container.encode(ids , forKey: .ids)
    try container.encode(c , forKey: .c)
    try container.encode(u , forKey: .u)
    try container.encode(d , forKey: .d)
}

public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    guard let contextUserInfoKey = CodingUserInfoKey.context,
        let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[contextUserInfoKey] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName:"Sync", in: managedObjectContext) else {  fatalError()  }

    self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    ids = try values.decode(Array?.self, forKey: .ids)
    c = try values.decode(Array.self, forKey: .c)
    u = try values.decode(Array.self, forKey: .u)
    d = try values.decode(Array.self, forKey: .d)
}
}
```

Updates+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Updates : Codable {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Updates> 
{
    return NSFetchRequest<Updates>(entityName: "Updates")
}

@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var ids: [String]?
@NSManaged public var c: [Parent]?
@NSManaged public var u: [Parent]?
@NSManaged public var d: [Parent]?
//** Here Parent is another Coredata entity model class. And sub entities are created from it. So at runtime c, u & d can have any of values amongst the sub-entities(Child, Clinic, Appointment etc.). So what happens is while decoding c, u and d it tries to decode "Parent" and not the subentities , becoz it doesnt know exact type of subentity(Child, Clinic, Appointment etc.). It just knows it as "Parent".

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name
    case ids = "sync_token"
    case c
    case u
    case d
}
}
```

JSON :

```
"updates": [
   {
     "name": "consultation_time",
     "ids": [ "id" ],
     "c": [
       {
         "id": 1,
         "_id": 1001,
         "is_active_morning": true,
         "morning_start_time": "2016-07-01T09:30:00.000+05:30",
         "morning_end_time": "2016-07-01T12:30:00.000+05:30",
         "is_active_evening": true,
         "evening_start_time": "2016-07-01T18:00:00.000+05:30",
         "evening_end_time": "2016-07-01T19:00:00.000+05:30",
         "day": "Monday",
         "doctor_id": 2,
         "clinic_id": 1
       }
     ],
     "u": [],
     "d": []
   },
   {
     "name": "child",
     "ids": [ "id" ],
     "c": [
       {
         "id": 1,
         "_id": 1022,
         "name": "Sarvesh",
         "gender": "male",
         "dob": "2017-01-01T17:48:20.393+05:30",
         "profile_image": "https://tpn-production.s3.amazonaws.com/710e34ae-49bb-11e7-99dc-      0a6eb743b653.jpg",
         "is_member": true,
         "email": "kiran@joshsoftware.com",
         "birthday_wish_sms": true,
         "program_launch_sms": true,
         "vaccine_reminder_same_day_sms": true,
         "vaccine_reminder_two_days_prior_sms": true,
         "vaccine_reminder_week_prior_sms": true,
         "parent_name": "Kiran"
       }
     ],
     "u": [],
     "d": []
   },
   {
     "name": "appointment",
     "ids": [ "id" ],
     "c": [
       {
         "id": 1,
         "_id": 1076,
         "start_time": "2016-07-01T19:10:00.000+05:30",
         "end_time": "2016-07-01T19:15:00.000+05:30",
         "schedule": "Evening",
         "status": "open",
         "weight": 9.2,
         "height": 45,
         "head_circumference": null,
         "temperature": null,
         "heart_rate": null,
         "blood_pressure": null,
         "respiratory_rate": null,
         "bill_amount": null,
         "child_id": 1,
         "doctor_id": 2,
         "clinic_id": 1,
         "amount_received_for_consultation": null,
         "amount_received_for_indoor_admission": null,
         "amount_received_for_nebulization": null,
         "amount_received_for_injection": null,
         "amount_received_for_vaccination": null,
         "payment_mode": null,
         "total_amount_received": null,
         "pending_amount_till_date": 100
       }
     ],
     "u": [],
     "d": []
   },
   {
     "name": "child_doctor",
     "ids": [ "id" ],
     "c": [
       {
         "id": 129089,
         "_id": null,
         "child_id": 12617,
         "doctor_id": 2,
         "clinic_id": 1
       }
     ],
     "u": [],
     "d": []
   },
   {
     "name": "clinic",
     "ids": [ "id" ],
     "c": [
       {
         "id": 1,
         "_id": 2701,
         "name": "Wellness Clinic",
         "landline": "02027654321",
         "address": {
           "address": "A13/14/15, Sunflower Apartments",
           "area": "Baner",
           "postal_code": "411045",
           "city": "Pune",
           "state": "MH",
           "country": "IN",
           "lat": "18.561338",
           "lng": "73.785545"
         },
         "mobile": null,
         "email": null
       }
     ],
     "u": [],
     "d": []
   },
   {
     "name": "clinics_user",
     "ids": [
       "id"
     ],
     "c": [
       {
         "id": 1,
         "clinic_id": 1,
         "is_active": true,
         "appointment_time_slot": 5,
         "consultation_rate": 400,
         "block_online_appointments_morning": false,
         "block_online_appointments_evening": false,
         "show_generic_name_first": false,
         "show_scheduled_vaccine": true,
         "show_regional_translation_of_number": false,
         "doctor_id": 2
       }
     ],
   "u": [],
   "d": []
 }
 ]
```

Comment: Considering that c is also a managed object, you can create a Parent Entity A. Now you can also create subentities of A, like entity B, C etc. Now when you want to use generic entity for property 'c' set its type to be of managed object A. Now you can set instances of B and C to property c as well. This comes with a caveat though a single table for A will be created in the db. Instances of B and C will also be stored in the same table causing performance issues.

Comment: @RohanBhale did as you said. But there's a problem. I have edited and put a comment in the question. See Updates+CoreDataProperties.swift code snippet.